# How to get a list of all user scripts that are called on startup?

Tags: startup

I have `emacs daemon` launching on startup and I have no idea where it is being launched. I've checked `systemd` and I don't have a service neither in `/etc/systemd/system` nor in `/usr/lib/systemd/system`. I've also checked `~/.config/autostart`, `.xinitrc`, and `.xprofile` without success, nowhere the daemon is being called. I have also grepped `/usr` and `/etc`.

How can I find the script that launches the daemon. Or more general: How can I find all user scripts that are launched on startup?

Edit: I'm running Arch Linux with Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

`initctl list` shell command can be used to display the contents of `/etc/init`

Comment: I don't even have a `/etc/init`.

Comment: that is weird, I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and it works for me.